# printf doesn't handle %zu

Tags: c, gcc, printf, mingw-w64

`printf` does not seem to correctly handle `%zu` in this program. On my machine it outputs

```
Is there anybody out there?
Size is: zu
```

where the expected output is

```
Is there anybody out there?
Size is: 27
```

It prints the expected output with `%u` but I think it should work with the `z` modifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE* text;
    errno_t ec;

    ec = fopen_s(&text, "text.txt", "r");

    if (ec) {
        fputs("Failed to read file", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char msg[28];
    fgets(msg, 28, text);

    puts(msg);
    printf("Size is: %zu\n", strlen(msg));

    fclose(text);
}
```

I'm compiling using gcc 6.3.0 (mingw-w64) with c11 enabled

Comment: Your question is about the %zu format specifier. So why did you submit a program with fopen, and other totally unrelated stuff?

Comment: mingw uses Microsoft Visual C runtime which doesn't support %zu.

Comment: more generally: conforming to a C standard concerns the compiler *and* the standard C library. Here, your compiler (`gcc`) conforms to C11, your library (`msvcrt`) only to C89.